# in Pandas, how to create a variable that is n for the nth observation within a group?

Tags: python, pandas

consider this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'C': [1, 2, 6,2]})

df
Out[128]: 
   B  C
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  b  6
3  b  2
```

I want to create a variable that simply corresponds to the ordering of observations after sorting by 'C' within each `groupby('B')` group.

```
df.sort_values(['B','C'])
Out[129]: 
   B  C  order
0  a  1  1
1  a  2  2
3  b  2  1
2  b  6  2
```

How can I do that? I am thinking about creating a column that is one, and using cumsum but that seems too clunky...

Comment: How about `df.C.rank()`?

Comment: Why do you want this variable? Maybe there is an easier way to do what you want.

Comment: @Noobie: please try to avoid substantial changes to your questions. Not only does it delay you getting an answer to your real question, it wastes the time of people who tried to answer the question you actually asked.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry about that. Although I can say that sometimes it is difficult to find the right example right away. Sometimes the answers proposed actually depend strongly on some simplistic features of the example.

Comment: "Right away?"  Until you've written a sufficiently detailed example which is clear about your needs, and not too simplified, don't ask the question.

Comment: ok got it sorry again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `range` with `len(df)`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'B': ['a', 'a', 'b'], 
                   'C': [5, 3, 2]})
print df
   A  B  C
0  1  a  5
1  2  a  3
2  3  b  2

df.sort_values(by='C', inplace=True)
#or without inplace
#df = df.sort_values(by='C')
print df
   A  B  C
2  3  b  2
1  2  a  3
0  1  a  5

df['order'] = range(1,len(df)+1) 
print df
   A  B  C  order
2  3  b  2      1
1  2  a  3      2
0  1  a  5      3
```

EDIT by comment:

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'C': [1, 2, 6,2]})

df.sort_values(['B','C'], inplace=True)
#or without inplace
#df = df.sort_values(['B','C'])

print df
   B  C
0  a  1
1  a  2
3  b  2
2  b  6

df['order'] = df.groupby('B', sort=False).cumcount() + 1
print df
   B  C  order
0  a  1      1
1  a  2      2
3  b  2      1
2  b  6      2
```

Comment: hi jezrael thanks. your solution seem to work, but I have sort by two columns or more, right?

Comment: Why do you think two or more columns?

Comment: because the ordering restart at zero for every group. please see my updated question. Maybe there is directly a groupby function that gives that?

Comment: jezrael, sorry about the changes above. i ll try to be more cautious next time

Comment: Aside: an alternative to `df = df.sort_values(...)` is `df.sort_values(..., inplace=True)`.

Comment: Instead of `transform(lambda foo)` you could just do `cumcount()` there.  Or `cumcount() + 1` as cumcount actually goes 0,1,2,... rather than 1,2,3,... as might have been expected for a count.

Comment: @Robᵩ - thank you, inplace is better. I add it to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with Jezrael's answer but there's a simpler (though less general) method in this particular example.  Just add groupby to JohnGalt's suggestion of using rank.

```
>>> df['order'] = df.groupby('B')['C'].rank()

   B  C  order
0  a  1    1.0
1  a  2    2.0
2  b  6    2.0
3  b  2    1.0
```

In this case, you don't really need the `['C']` but it makes the ranking a little more explicit and if you had other unrelated columns in the dataframe then you would need it.

But if you are ranking by more than 1 column, you should use Jezrael's method.

Comment: interesting finding! does it matter not to specify the `method` in rank? could we have problems if there are missing values?